# Why square brackets are used in dtf.loc[] in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering why it is `dtf.loc[x]` instead of `dtf.loc(x)`. I've read that `loc` is a property so it makes sense because it isn't a function call, but now I don't know why someone made it a property (don't know a lot about properties) instead of a function - it would be more intuitive to me.

Comment: The important part here is not that `loc` is a property, but that it's an object that supports `__getitem__`. I guess the pandas devs wanted Dataframes to feels similar to numpy arrays with respect to item selection.

Comment: This enables to use the slicing syntax (e.g., `df.loc[:2:-1]`), which would be impossible with a function (it would raise a `SyntaxError`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<rant>Because Pandas is not Python</rant>...

More seriously, Pandas is a nice library which uses the poserful numpy (part os scipy) module to process large arrays at C speed. But it comes at the price of some caveats:

- to be consistent with numpy, indexing accept a tuple of integers or slices. And this is required in numpy to be able to *vectorize* (use C high speed routines) the accesses
- `loc` is just a property of a dataframe that returns the indexer. It has to be a specific property because `df[x]` is already defined to be the `x` column of the `df` dataframe

It could have been a mere function, which would be less disrupting for Python users. But it was essential too to make clear that it was an **indexing** access. And (the reason for my initial rant), efficiency and consistency with numpy is more important in Pandas that consistency with core Python. A good example for that is the equality between two Series. For consistency with numpy, is is also a Series and **not** a boolean. But it just break a number of Python goodies, preventing to use `in` to check whether a Python container of Series contains a specific Series:

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
b = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])

pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) in [a, b]
```

raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) in [a, b]
  File "...Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1442, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What to learn from that: just accept the fact that Pandas syntax is sometimes inconsistant with Python normal usage...